# smo doesnot display installed instances in w2k8 sql2k8 cluster?

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows, cluster-computing

I have cretaed an application via COM interoperability(using SMO and created a dll consume it in c++) which retrieves the local instances of sqlserver(basically try for network instances and from that trace out for local to make it as work for remote discovery of sqlinstances).
it is  worked in all cases except win2k8sql2k8 cluster it worked for win2k3and sql2k8 cluster also.

it seem to be exception occured in COM dll connection issue.But the same is work win2k8 sql2008 non cluster

do i need any work around????

any help regard this............

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In a cluster there is no 'local' instance. Even though it runs on a physical node at any one time, the instance is logically located on the cluster resource name and address. Since your application cannot run on the cluster resource, by definition a clustered instance cannot be 'local'.

Answer (score 0):

@Rames Rusan                                                                                              what is alternative for this

Comment: You need to list the instances on the 'cluster' name.

Comment: means i have to give the cluster name..this already i did.that y i told working for w2k3 sql2k8 cluster but failed in w2k8sql2k8 cluster only.